# Deriving FromRow on a type with [String] field

Tags: postgresql, haskell, deriving, postgresql-simple

I am building a haskell server with a postgres database.  I am using postgresql-simple to query the db.

I have the following type:

```
data Reading = Reading
  { id :: UUID
  , title :: String
  , authors :: [String]
  , startDate :: Day
  , finishDate :: Maybe Day
  }
  deriving (Eq, Show, Generic, FromRow)
```

This results in the following compiler error:

```
No instance for (Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.FromField.FromField
                        [String])
       arising from a use of ‘Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.FromRow.$dmfromRow’
```

In the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.7.0.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-FromField.html#t:FromField), I do not see an instance defined for `[String]`.  It seems like one should exist.  Is there one I can use or should I be thinking about defining my own?

Edit:

I can define

```
instance FromRow Reading where
  fromRow =
    Reading
      <$> field
      <*> field
      <*> (fromPGArray <$> field)
      <*> field
      <*> field
```

But this goes into cumbersome territory.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use `Vector String` that is already defined?

Comment: No, let me give that a shot later today!

Comment: @rajashekar running into issues with `Vector String` when trying to derive `FromForm` on the data type to allow POST from a form